# sum of rows,columns and diagonals of a matrix

Tags: c++, c, c++11

Program to find the maximum among the sums of the diagonals,rows and columns of a matrix. Cannot find the problem with the diagonal sum code.

FOR input:

```
2
16 4
-3 5
```

expected output should be 21 whereas the actual output is 9.

```
#include<stdio.h>
//Main Function

int main()
{
int n,a[101][101],i,j;
int max=0,sum=0;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
}
j=0;

    //COLOUMN SUM
    while(j<n)
{
    sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        sum+=a[i][j];
        if(sum>max)
        max=sum;
        j++;
} 
i=0;
//ROW SUM
    while(i<n)
{
    sum=0;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    sum+=a[i][j];        
        i++;
        if(sum>max)
        max=sum;
    }

     //DIAGONAL SUM the main problem
sum=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
     for(j=0;j<n;j++)
     {
       if(i==j)
       sum+=a[i][j];
      }
}

if(sum>max)
max=sum;
sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
            if(i+j==n-1)
    sum+=a[i][j];
    }
}
if(sum>max)
max=sum;
printf("%d",max);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Don't try to write a program that is valid both for C and for C++. This is extremely difficult and you end up with something that is not quite either of the languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read into array incorrectly:

```
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
```

This should be:

```
scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
```

Comment: well thats correct.Thanks.Such a stupid mistake it was.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `j` in the read loop?

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]); // <== Why no j here?????
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you had not read elements into the array properly
   just change this statement you will get correct answer
   scanf("%d",&a[i]) to scanf("%d",&a[i][j])